# Optimal search method to find float number in a sorted bucket list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, floating-point, range

The problem I'm trying to solve is to find what bucket a given float number will be.

Say that there are ten buckets.
In bucket 0 I'm putting the numbers in the range [0 to 1.2].

- bucket 1 [1.2 to 2.4]
- bucket 2 [2.4 to 3.6]
  and so on until
- bucket 9 [10.8 to 12.0]

The buckets are sorted and have the same 'width' (1.2 in this example).

- with linear search, the computation complexity will be **O(n)**
- with tree search, the computation complexity will be **O(log n)**

Is there a method that allows the computation complexity to be **O(1)**?
It feels like there should be some hashing or math "trick" that would make the search more efficient, but I can't find/think of one.

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL9Ay.png)

Comment: Are the bucket always the same size? If so, the relevant bucket is `floor(f/bucket_size)` (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Form your example, seems like the buckets are all of the same size.

If this is the case, and for buckets of size `S`, the relevant bucket for some float `f` is:

```
#bucket = floor(f/S)
```

This is basically "normalizing" to assign `S` as 1, and leaving the reminder out.

(Note, this assumes intervals are one sided open, i.e. `1.2` is in bucket1 in your example, not bucket0. This can be easily checked and handle if this assumption does not hold though.)

Comment: Yeah, that would work!
Even if bucket 0 doesn't start at 0.0 I can calculate the difference from f to start value, and use that formula to find the bucket, making the search run in O(1)!
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Step one: divide value by width:

```
double width = 1.2;
assert(x >= 0 && x < 12.0);

double q = x/width;
int expected_bucket = (int) q;
```

Since the `x` and `width` are FP values, the quotient `x/width` is subject to the usually FP issues or rounding/inexactness.  Hopefully the insertion code and search code behave alike, yet edge cases may fail.  A more fault tolerant search could look into a neighboring bucket.

Yet using a common helper function of `int x_to_bucket(double x)` should provide sufficient consistent results.

---

Note: I'd expect buckets range to *not* include one end.

Instead of

```
[0.0 to 1.2]
[1.2 to 2.4]
[2.4 to 3.6]
```

... this.  Note `)` vs. `]`

```
[0.0 to 1.2)
[1.2 to 2.4)
[2.4 to 3.6)
```